# How can I discover which website was under my IP before?

Tags: security, server, ip, google-search-console, blacklist

I hired a web server in Brazil (Locaweb), and now that my website is live my guests can't enter because says that my IP is in a blacklist.

Ok, I understand about blacklist and I know that usually servers recycle IP's. I requested Google to check it using the Webmaster Tools and they said that my website is clean now, there is no malicious code anymore.

It would be perfect if other websites, like Bing or Yahoo does the same! Also some antivirus, like Avast and AVG. There is an easy way to do it? Or the best option is to ask for another IP?

About my question, I'm asking it, because I think the IP was a porn website before. There is also a way to check it?

Ah, my IP:

> 191.252.59.101

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/finding-old-domain-whois-information-with-domaintools-domain-history/) seems to have some good advice on how to find historical whois information.

Aside from that, you can try to reach out to whoever maintains the blacklist you're on, but it'd probably be easier to just request a new IP.